# How can I fix the size of the video so it is the exact size of the screen?

Tags: texturing, materials

[image]

How can I fix the size of the video so it is the exact size of the screen?

Comment: In your image node, select "Extend" instead of "Repeat".  Assuming that only the *screen* area is mapped to the UV being used.

Comment: Remap the UV or adjust the scale on the Mapping node. If you plug a Value node into the Scale plug you can adjust them simultaneously.